# Animating a rectangle in PyQT5: Why is QtCore not defined?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to animate a rectangle in PyQT by creating an animation loop. I have done this in TKinter using the `window.after()` method and am trying to do the same thing in PyQt5 using `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot()`, however, when I run the code it says that `QtCore` is not defined yet I believe that I have imported it!? Also - would this method work anyway? Is there a better method?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


def animate():
    global a
    global x
    mw.paintEvent = paintEvent
    a = a+1
    x = x+1
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(33, animate)


def paintEvent(e):
    qp = QPainter()
    qp.begin(mw)
    qp.setBrush(QColor(200, 0, 0))
    qp.drawRect(a, b, x, y)
    qp.end()

a = 10
b = 15
x = 90
y = 60

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

mw = QMainWindow()
mw.setWindowTitle('PyQt5 - Main Window')
mw.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icon.jpg"))
mw.resize(300,100)

animate()

mw.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QtCore` reference is undefined because you are using a star import:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
```

this imports everything that is *inside* `QtCore` into the global namespace but it does *not* import the name `QtCore`.

In fact you can use:

```
QTimer.singleShot(x)
```

without the need for `QtCore.` in front.

However you should probably use:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
```

This said:

I have no idea why you are using the `singleShot` timer when you do **not** want a single shot timer but a period one. You should do something like:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setBrush(QColor(200, 0, 0))
        qp.drawRect(a, b, x, y)
        qp.end()


def updateValues():
    global a, x
    a += 1
    x += 1
    mw.update()  # <-- update the window!


a = 10
b = 15
x = 90
y = 60

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

mw = MyWindow()
mw.setWindowTitle('PyQt5 - Main Window')
mw.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icon.jpg"))
mw.resize(300,100)

timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(updateValues)
timer.start(33)

mw.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The `QTimer` object called with `start(msec)` will emit a `timeout()` signal every `msec` milliseconds. In this way you don't have to restart it every time.

Moreover I find really ugly to patch instances by changing their methods like you are doing in `animate()` with `mw.paintEvent = paintEvent`. Besides: you could put that line outside the function.

**Note**: Inside the function that updates the values you have to call `mw.update()` otherwise no `paintEvent` is generated.
Moreover it seems like `timer` is getting garbage collected, thus blocking the timer so it's better to just have a global reference to it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I know the code is ugly - I just find it easier to learn writing procedural code and then OOP once I have understood. Also the code above that you have suggested doesn't seem to animate. My solution did but it was a bit buggy - it only updated when i dragged the window smaller or larger. Any ideas why?

Comment: @sw123456 I just fixed the problem. The error was pretty simple: you forgot to call `update()` or `repaint()`, so no `paintEvent` was ever generated and thus the window wasn't updated. It was updated when resizing because resizing causes `paintEvent`s.

Comment: Fantastic spot! Thank you so much - it is always the simple ones! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You haven't imported QTCore, you've imported everything *in* QTCore.

### Change the way you import

Try changing this:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
```

to this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
```

### Or, change the way you call QTimer

change this:

```
QTCore.QTimer.singleShot(33, animate)
```

to this:

```
QTImer.singleShot(33, animate)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you once again Bryan. It now runs BUT the rectangle doesn't move on its own - the window doesn't update the drawing unless I drag the window larger or smaller - any ideas why this is?

Comment: I think I have just had this last question answered! Thanks

Comment: Actually, I still haven't - any ideas why the rectangle doesn't update properly? It is very buggy for some reason - only updates rectangle when the window is resized!?

Comment: OK, all fixed - didn't add the line mw.update() in the animation loop. Thanks again for your help!